# Adding more images to the canvas to drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I want to be able to spawn a new image to the canvas at the click of a button, rather than having to manually edit the code.

I have the following HTML5/JavaScript code that allows images to be dragged and dropped between multiple canvases and it works perfectly for what I require.

**What I am doing:**

```
<canvas style="float: left" height="125" width="400" id="cvs1">[No canvas support]</canvas>
<canvas style="float: left; margin-left: 100px" height="125" width="400" id="cvs2">[No canvas support]</canvas>

<script src="http://www.rgraph.net/libraries/RGraph.common.core.js" ></script>

<script>
    window.onload = function ()
    {
        var canvas1 = document.getElementById("cvs1");
        var canvas2 = document.getElementById("cvs2");
        var context1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
        var context2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
        var imageXY  = {x: 5, y: 5};




        /**
        * This draws the image to the canvas
        */
        function Draw ()
        {
            //Clear both canvas first
            canvas1.width = canvas1.width
            canvas2.width = canvas2.width
            
            //Draw a red rectangle around the image
            if (state && state.dragging) {
                state.canvas.getContext('2d').strokeStyle = 'red';
                state.canvas.getContext('2d').strokeRect(imageXY.x - 2.5,
                                                         imageXY.y - 2.5,
                                                         state.image.width + 5,
                                                         state.image.height + 5);
            }
            
            // Now draw the image
            state.canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(state.image, imageXY.x, imageXY.y);
        }




        canvas2.onclick =
        canvas1.onclick = function (e)
        {
            
            if (state && state.dragging) {
                state.dragging = false;
                Draw();
                return;
            }





            var mouseXY = RGraph.getMouseXY(e);

            state.canvas    = e.target;
            
            if (   mouseXY[0] > imageXY.x
                && mouseXY[0] < (imageXY.x + state.image.width)
                && mouseXY[1] > imageXY.y
                && mouseXY[1] < (imageXY.y + state.image.height)) {

                state.dragging       = true;
                state.originalMouseX = mouseXY[0];
                state.originalMouseY = mouseXY[1];
                state.offsetX         = mouseXY[0] - imageXY.x;
                state.offsetY         = mouseXY[1] - imageXY.y;

            }
        }

        canvas1.onmousemove =
        canvas2.onmousemove = function (e)
        {

            if (state.dragging) {
            
                state.canvas = e.target;
                
                var mouseXY = RGraph.getMouseXY(e);
                
                // Work how far the mouse has moved since the mousedon event was triggered
                var diffX = mouseXY[0] - state.originalMouseX;
                var diffY = mouseXY[1] - state.originalMouseY;

                imageXY.x = state.originalMouseX + diffX - state.offsetX;
                imageXY.y = state.originalMouseY + diffY - state.offsetY;
                
                Draw();
                
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
        }

        /**
        * Load the image on canvas1 initially and set the state up with some defaults
        */
        state = {}
        state.dragging     = false;
        state.canvas       = document.getElementById("cvs1");
        state.image        =  new Image();
        state.image.src    = 'http://www.rgraph.net/images/logo.png';
        state.offsetX      = 0;
        state.offsetY      = 0;

        state.image.onload = function ()
        {
            Draw();
        }
    }
</script>
```

This can also be seen on this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NehQX/1/) (Note: you have to click the image before you can drag it)

**The problem I am having:**

I would like to add more images to the canvases so that any of the images can then be dragged and dropped between however many canvases I choose to create.

I can quite easily add more canvases to the page to drag and drop between, **however when it comes to adding/spawning more images to the canvases I cannot get it to work.**

The only way I can think of being able to do this is by repeating the `Draw()` function for every single image that gets added. That would mean if I wanted 30 images to be able to drag and drop between 10 different canvases for example, I would need to repeat the `Draw()` function 30 times. Surely that cannot be the best way to do this?

Unless I am missing something very obvious I cannot see another way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s how to configure your code to create multiple objects and click-drag between canvases.

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Bnb6A/

[image]

Code an object factory function that creates new draggable objects and put all new objects in an array.

Keep this information about each draggable object:

- dragging (true/false) indicating if this object is currently being dragged
- image: the image for this object
- x,y: the current top,left position of this object
- width,height: the size of this object
- offsetX,offsetY: indicates where the mouse clicked relative to top,left of this object
- draw: (a function) that allows this object to draw itself (surrounded by a red rect if it’s being dragged)

On click:

- Get the mouse position
- Clear both canvases
- Iterate through the object array
- If an object is being dragged, unset the dragging flag
- If an object is now selected, set the dragging flag and set the offsetX,offsetY for the starting mouse position relative to this object.
- Redraw all objects

On mousemove:

- Get the mouse position
- Clear both canvases
- Iterate through the object array
- If an object is being dragged, move it to the mouse position (setting x,y adjusted for the offset)
- Redraw all objects

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:20px; }
    canvas{ border: 1px solid #808080; }
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){

        var canvas1 = document.getElementById("cvs1");
        var canvas2 = document.getElementById("cvs2");

        var contexts=[];
        contexts.push(canvas1.getContext('2d'));
        contexts.push(canvas2.getContext('2d'));


        function clearAll(){
            //Clear both canvas first
            canvas1.width = canvas1.width
            canvas2.width = canvas2.width
        }

        canvas1.onclick=function(e){ handleClick(e,1); };
        canvas2.onclick=function(e){ handleClick(e,2); };
        //
        function handleClick(e,contextIndex){
            e.stopPropagation();

            var mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-e.target.offsetLeft);
            var mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-e.target.offsetTop);

            clearAll();

            for(var i=0;i<states.length;i++){

                var state=states[i];

                if(state.dragging){
                    state.dragging=false;
                    state.draw();
                    continue;
                }

                if ( state.contextIndex==contextIndex
                    && mouseX>state.x && mouseX<state.x+state.width
                    && mouseY>state.y && mouseY<state.y+state.height)
                {
                    state.dragging=true;
                    state.offsetX=mouseX-state.x;
                    state.offsetY=mouseY-state.y;
                    state.contextIndex=contextIndex;
                }

                state.draw();
            }
        }

        canvas1.onmousemove = function(e){ handleMousemove(e,1); }
        canvas2.onmousemove = function(e){ handleMousemove(e,2); }
        //
        function handleMousemove(e,contextIndex){
            e.stopPropagation();

            var mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-e.target.offsetLeft);
            var mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-e.target.offsetTop);

            clearAll();

            for(var i=0;i<states.length;i++){

                var state=states[i];

                if (state.dragging) {
                    state.x = mouseX-state.offsetX;
                    state.y = mouseY-state.offsetY;
                    state.contextIndex=contextIndex;
                }
                state.draw();
            }
        }


        var states=[];

        var img=new Image();
        img.onload=function(){
            states.push(addState(0,0,img));
        }
        img.src="http://www.rgraph.net/images/logo.png";




        function addState(x,y,image){
                state = {}
                state.dragging=false;
                state.contextIndex=1;
                state.image=image;
                state.x=x;
                state.y=y;
                state.width=image.width;
                state.height=image.height;
                state.offsetX=0;
                state.offsetY=0;
                state.draw=function(){
                    var context=contexts[this.contextIndex-1];
                    if (this.dragging) {
                        context.strokeStyle = 'red';
                        context.strokeRect(this.x,this.y,this.width+5,this.height+5)
                    }
                    context.drawImage(this.image,this.x,this.y);
                }
                state.draw();
                return(state);
        }

        $("#more").click(function(){
            states.push(addState(states.length*100,0,img));
        });


    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
  <button id="more">Add Image</button><br>
  <canvas height="125" width="300" id="cvs1">[No canvas support]</canvas><br>
  <canvas height="125" width="300" id="cvs2">[No canvas support]</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Excellent, that's exactly the kind of thing I was looking for and a great explanation thank you very much - Also, I know how to hard-code new working canvases (as I've done here http://jsfiddle.net/YM7Vc/4/) but how would I go about creating new canvases at the click of a button (so that the images can be dragged in and out of the newly created ones as well?) - Thanks for all your help

Comment: Glad I could help :) The only trick to dynamically creating new canvases is to add a contextIndex property to each new canvas.  That way you can wire up the mouse event handlers including that contextIndex.  See this quick example:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/2gv4J/

Comment: Thanks for the example again. Using http://jsfiddle.net/perl_user/QZ7Zd/ I have tried multiple ways of adding the 'Add a new canvas' feature, the new canvases get created correctly but whatever I try does not allow the images to be dragged and dropped onto the new canvases that get created (it still lets me drag and drop between the three original canvases though). Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated once again - thanks

Comment: I see that your creating new canvases.  But for each dynamically added canvas, you need to: (1) wire them up to the mouse events, (2) add their contexts to the contexts array and you also must (3) change clearAll to iterate through the contexts array instead of acting on just the pre-existing canvases.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I believe I have now done number (2) - added their contexts to the context array and (3) - changed clearAll to iterate through the context array as shown here http://jsfiddle.net/perl_user/QZ7Zd/ but I have obviously done something wrong in the clearAll part because it leaves a ghost behind the images when dragging?. I think I have also done (1) - wired them to the mouse events as well but I am not sure if I have done this properly/correctly? If you could help with this that would be great, thanks a lot

Comment: You are close! Remember the canvas elements are tied to the mouse events by a number (1,2...) so if you want to have the canvas id be addedcanvases1, you would need to change the mousehandlers to recognize "addedcanvases1" instead of just "1". Also, events are wired to html elements, not contexts so you wire-up like this:   newCanvas.onclick = function (e) { handleClick(e, this.contextIndex);  Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/eNT9m/  Good luck with your project :)
                };

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much - I now have it working (shown here http://jsfiddle.net/perl_user/s849g). However there is one other issue I have noticed that I'm really hoping you can also help with which is... if you add enough new canvases so that you have to scroll down to reach the bottom ones when you try and drag and drop an image to those canvases it kind of breaks and mucks up the dragging and dropping? Any help with this would be much appreciated - Thanks for all you've done so far.

Comment: You have to account for the amount of scrolling using $(document).scrollTop()

Comment: add to each mouseX/mouseY.

Comment: Works perfectly - I've learnt a lot from all your help, thank you very much indeed - http://jsfiddle.net/perl_user/s849g/

Comment: Oops! I mis-spoke in my scrollTop comment above. You should add scrollTop to mouseY and add scrollLeft to your mouseX.

Comment: That's ok, I realized eventually :). I didn't add the scrollLeft part though so thanks for the heads up on that. Any thoughts on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20177273/html5-canvas-grouping-attaching-an-image-to-a-canvas? thanks