# HTML5 Canvas - Grouping / Attaching an image TO a canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, canvas

Using this **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/perl_user/s849g/)** I am able to press a button to add new canvases to the screen...

```
var next = 4

    function addCanvas() {
        // create a new canvas element
        var newCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        newCanvas.id = "addedcanvases" + next; //added this to give each new canvas a unique id
        next++;
        newCanvas.width = canvasWidth;
        newCanvas.height = canvasHeight;
        // add a context for the new canvas to the contexts[] array
        contexts.push(newCanvas.getContext("2d"));
        // link the new canvas to its context in the contexts[] array
        newCanvas.contextIndex = contexts.length;
        // wire up the click handler
        newCanvas.onclick = function (e) {
            handleClick(e, this.contextIndex);
        };
        // wire up the mousemove handler
        newCanvas.onmousemove = function (e) {
            handleMousemove(e, this.contextIndex);
        };
        // add the new canvas to the page
        document.body.appendChild(newCanvas);
    }
```

**The problem:**

What is the best way to go about grouping / attaching a **static image** to the top of a canvas (as shown in the image below) so that whenever a new canvas is created in **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/perl_user/s849g/)** an image is automatically created with it that is grouped / attached to the top of the new canvas.

This is so that where-ever a new canvas is dynamically created on the page an image is put above that canvas?

[image: canvas with image grouped / attached to the top of them]

There may be an obvious way to do this that I am overlooking? but googling has not thrown up much as all 'image' and 'canvas' searches inevitably relate to actually adding an image to the canvas - which is not what I want to do in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's taking @KaliedaRik's answer and creating your groups using javascript:

http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/3EUnc/

The code to create a new group could be something like this:

```
function newGroup(){

    // create a new wrapper div
    var div=document.createElement("div");
    div.className="wrapper";

    // create an img and a canvas element

    var img=document.createElement("img");
    var br=document.createElement("br");
    img.style.width="50px";
    img.src="houseicon.png";
    var canvas=document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width=300;
    canvas.height=55;

    // add the img and canvas elements to the wrapper div

    div.appendChild(img);
    div.appendChild(br);
    div.appendChild(canvas);

    // add the wrapper div with its contained img + canvas to the page

    document.body.appendChild(div);

}
```

Comment: Excellent - works perfectly and thanks for the comments. What is making the canvases appear underneath each other each time a new one is added rather than next to each other until the page width is used as they were previously? thanks a lot

Comment: Glad I helped...If you want each new group to be to the right of the previous group, check out the CSS float:left directive: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: Thanks for the link - The image gets successfully added with the canvas now thanks -  http://jsfiddle.net/perl_user/TBh4k/

Comment: I have a last question I am hoping you will be able to provide some assistance with, thank you very much - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20182133/html5-canvas-saving-and-restoring-drag-and-drop-canvas-states

Comment: @markE I'm also looking for this problem too. How do you apply delete in here? not the canvas but the image that was selected.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution: when you create the canvas element, create a new **div** at the same time and put the **canvas** and **img** tags inside it. By making the div position style relative and the contained canvas and img position styles absolute, you'll be able to place the image wherever it needs to go.

```
<div style="position: relative">
    <canvas style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;"></canvas>
    <img src="whatever" alt="whatever" style="position: absolute; top: -20px; left: 0px" />
</div>
```

Comment: I agree...create a div element that wraps both the img and canvas elements.  Since the image is desired statically above the canvas, you don't even need positioning, just (pseudocode): <div><img/><canvas/></div>.